# Text Extraction using pdfbox library based on the co-ordinates and Rectangle2D.Double

Tags: pdfbox

I am trying to extract the text based on the co-ordinates/positions of words from a pdf file using pdfbox library.

Steps I followed till now :

- I used the "PrintTextLocations" class to get the positions. I made a
  trial for extracting text in a specific area by constructing a
  `Rectangle2D.Double` object. But, if I try to relate steps 1 & step 2
  , I could not find any similarity like x and y coordinates, width and
  height. My doubt here is, how can I extract text by clubbing both the
  ways like this:
- > get the positions of characters
  >   build an area(rectangle) with them
  >   extract the text from that region.
  >   for ex: CAT. is the word I wanted to extract from the pdf.

  - String[441.38,411.02002 fs=8.0 xscale=8.0 height=5.544
     space=2.2240002 width=5.776001]**C**
    String[447.156,411.02002 fs=8.0
     xscale=8.0 height=5.544 space=2.2240002 width=5.776001]**A**
     String[452.932,411.02002 fs=8.0 xscale=8.0 height=5.544
     space=2.2240002 width=4.8880005]**T** 
  String[457.82,411.02002 fs=8.0
     xscale=8.0 height=5.544 space=2.2240002 width=2.223999]**.**

I am extracting the same word by building an area with the following dimensions.    `Rectangle2D.Double head1ColTwo = new Rectangle2D.Double( 300, 380,160, 35 );`
this is the rectangle area which I built and successfully obtained the word "CAT."
The reason why I am following this way is, I have some fields in my database and only a human can read and get the values for those fields. I want to automate that process. The major problem here is, the field names will not be there in the  pdf file.
Please suggest me if this is the correct way according to my requirement mentioned in the above paragraph, if not , suggest the alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Your problems are due to a PDFBox quirk, in its text extraction code it uses coordinates in different coordinate systems. E.g. in the `PrintTextLocations` method `writeString` the output is generated like this:

```
for (TextPosition text : textPositions)
{
    System.out.println( "String[" + text.getXDirAdj() + "," +
            text.getYDirAdj() + " fs=" + text.getFontSize() + " xscale=" +
            text.getXScale() + " height=" + text.getHeightDir() + " space=" +
            text.getWidthOfSpace() + " width=" +
            text.getWidthDirAdj() + "]" + text.getUnicode() );
}
```

and in the `PDFTextStripperByArea` class (I assume you use this class for extraction *based on the co-ordinates and Rectangle2D.Double*) it filters like this:

```
if( rect.contains( text.getX(), text.getY() ) )
```

The coordinates returned by `getX` and `getY` and those returned by `getXDirAdj` and `getYDirAdj` can differ substantially. Both are based on the actual default user space coordinates but

- `getX` and `getY` are derived using the PDF page **Rotate** entry, and
- `getXDirAdj` and `getYDirAdj` are derived using a rotation derived from the current transformation matrix.

Thus, I would propose reading the same coordinates from the `TextPosition` as are used by the `PDFTextStripperByArea` filtering